# How to add a submenu page in Adobe Flex

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flash-builder

I have added submenu in menu bar in adobe Flex. menu A has submenu A1 A2 A3 like that.
right now Submenu is not performing any action ,i want open a page in submenu in the same frame .
Please suggest me how to achieve it.

thanks,
Gaurav

Comment: Show the code, please.

Answer (score 0):

it might help

```
var url:String = "http://www.example.com/";
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
try {
    navigateToURL(request, '_self');//here you can add secound param and set target like in html "_self", "_blank" etc.
} catch (e:Error) {
    trace("Error occurred!");
}
```

Comment: Hi anton, 
Thanx for the prompt reply .
Actually, what i am trying to achieve is : to open other flex pages on click of menu and submenus .
For Example :
I am creating website which is having 10 pages .
One Master/Main/Front Page and 9 Child/sub pages .
On front Page there is Menu Bar , like HOME ABOUT US SERVICES PRODUCTS etc.. and each Menu has submenu items .
Now if i click on any subitem of SERVICES, it should navigate to that particular page .

Simply I am loking to achieve how can i navigate to other pages from Main Page in adobe flex by using MENU BAR .

Regards,
Gaurav